# Creating multiple Java objects inside Loop and using all outside

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

I want to create multiple objects inside while loop and access all objects outside in JAVA 8.
Currently using a list to store the obects, but all objects get replaced by one last object (last created).

I have tried initializing list inside try, outside try, nothing works.

Here is my test1.java,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        List<test2> objList=new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader encReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./asd.txt"));
        String eachLine;
        while ((eachLine = encReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = eachLine.split("\\|");
            if(true){
                objList.add(new test2(data[0], data[1]));
            }
        }   // While ends here

        objList.forEach(x -> x.printEncLoc());

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my test2.java,

```
public class test2 {
private static String s1;
private static String s2;
test2(String s1new, String s2new){
    s1=s1new;
    s2=s2new;
}
public static void printEncLoc(){
    System.out.println("s1:"+s1+" s2:"+s2);
}
}
```

Here is my input file example (asd.txt)

```
hello|123
qwe|klj
```

It calls only the last object's printEncLoc function each time in the forEach line. 
It prints output as follows.

```
s1:qwe s2:klj
s1:qwe s2:klj
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: _"It calls only the last objects function "_ -- sorry, you will need to explain what you mean here more explicitly.  What do you mean by "last object" and "function"?

Comment: last object is the object of the class EncodeLocation created for last line of the file (which is assigned to eachLine). 
Function is printEncLoc function inside the EncodeLocation class.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] and show sample input data and corresponding output.

Comment: 1. Can you check your size of list?
2. Is your if condition in loop is causing only object to be added to the list?
Code looks fine, it is creating new object if that line hits

Comment: Gorav Singal Size of the list is fine, same as number of lines in the file. Currently I'm just trying with sample txt file such that all lines will pass and go inside if condition. I have printed in the constructor and also checked, so if condition is fine. Also,  I can see different objects stored in the list (by directly printing it), but when I call the function using each object it is calling only the last object's function. Is all the objects created in the same place in stack or something?

Comment: @HarinathSrinivas did you check whether all the created objects are different or same? I tried your logic and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Lalit Mehra,  did you put the try block? and other if condition blocks? coz I am not sure where exactly the objects are deleted (via garbage collector) here.

Comment: @GhostCat Jim Garrison ok, I have pasted the complete files now, with the sample txt file and output as well.

Comment: I think the code outputs same lines both times is because you are using static variables ... in class test2, make everything non-static (variables and method) and then it will print out different lines

Comment: @mettleap got it. Thanks

Comment: Basically that renders your question a DUP of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098419/static-and-non-static-fields

Comment: Unrelated: class names in Java go UpperCamelCase. So dont start them with a lowercase letter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the properties in test2 static, this means all instances share the same properties. So when you change them for the 2nd row, the 1st row changes as well.

Remove the 'static' from s1 and s2, and from your printEncLoc() method and your code works.

EDIT: See https://www.baeldung.com/java-static for more on how static works