# Why java takes old variable value of one class from another?

Tags: java

There is two classes:

```
public class Main {
    int a = 4;
    Second second = new Second();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main(); 
        main.doAll();
    } 

    public void doAll() {
        second.printInt();
        second.printInt2();

        a = 5;

        second.printInt();
        second.printInt2();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Second {

    public void printInt() {
        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println("a from printInt1: " + main.a);
    }

    public void printInt2() {
        int a = new Main().a;
        System.out.println("a from printInt2 " + a);
    }
}
```

The result of it:

```
a from printInt1: 4
a from printInt2: 4
a from printInt1: 4
a from printInt2: 4
```

As you can see, `a` didn`t change for methods of `Second`. But I can't understand why does this happen. This is how I see it:

1. Second's instance creates in the Main
2. Second's methods calling from Main
3. Second's methods creating **new** Main instance and print `a = 4`
4. Second's methods calling again, creating Main instance again and print `a` of the **new** instance (so it should be 5)

But its never changes. I'm new at Java, so I really can't find mistake in this logic.

UPD: This question also answered here: [Static and non static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098419/static-and-non-static-fields), as I can't delete my answered one

Comment: It is because you are creating new instances of Main class in your methods. And every new instance has variable `a` set to 4

Comment: Try this when declare a=5 try this.a=5

Comment: You have to understand what it means that fields belong to objects (non static). You probably assume that there is exactly one `a` ... but there isn't. The whole story changes when you put `static` in front of the declaration of `a` in Main.

Comment: Try my answer :}

Comment: Yeshwin Verma The Programmer, Iit doesn`t work(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In both `printInt` and `printInt2` you create a **new** `Main` method and access that instances `a`. Since during construction `a` will always be set to `4`, that's the only value you see.

If you want `printInt` and `printInt2` to access the `a` field of the `Main` instance you create in your `main` method, then you'll need to pass it to them in some way.

One option is a parameter in the `Second` constructor (i.e. `new Second(main)`), in which case you'd need to hold on to it in a field in `Second`.

Another option that requires fewer changes is to simply pass the `Main` instance you want to use directly to the `printInt`/`printInt2` method: `second.printInt(main)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are referencing the Variable `a` from the `Main()` class. And it's value in the `Main()` class is set to 4.

Inside the print methods you create new `Main()` objects (`Main main = new Main();`). Then you are referencing the variable `a` of these created `Main()` objects, whose value is 4.

`a` is set to 5 inside a method called `doAll()`. It's only valid inside this method, but not outside.

Answer (score -2):

In the second class add

```
public class Second {

    public void printInt() {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.doAll();
        System.out.println("a from printInt1: " + main.a);
    }

    public void printInt2() {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.doAll()
        int a = new main.a;
        System.out.println("a from printInt2 " + a);
    }
}
```